# Append a Dict to a Dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary that looks like this :

```
{'BOB':  [['AUDI', 'BLACK', 'PETROL'],
          ['MINI', 'PINK', 'PETROL'],
          ['VW', 'BLUE', 'DIESEL']],
 'DAVE': [['BMW', 'PURPLE', 'PETROL'],
          ['VOLVO', 'GREY', 'PETROL']]}
```

What Im looking for is to add a dict to each keys list. The dict would be something like :

```
{'TYRE': RUBBER, 'ALLOY': 17, 'SUNROOF': YES}
```

The end result would look like :

```
{'BOB':  [['AUDI', 'BLACK', 'PETROL',
           {'TYRE': RUBBER, 'ALLOY': 17, 'SUNROOF': YES}],
          ['MINI', 'PINK', 'PETROL',
           {'TYRE': RUBBER, 'ALLOY': 17, 'SUNROOF': YES}]
# ...
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dic={'BOB':  [['AUDI', 'BLACK', 'PETROL'],
          ['MINI', 'PINK', 'PETROL'],
          ['VW', 'BLUE', 'DIESEL']],
 'DAVE': [['BMW', 'PURPLE', 'PETROL'],
          ['VOLVO', 'GREY', 'PETROL']]}
dic1={'TYRE': 'RUBBER', 'ALLOY': 17, 'SUNROOF': 'YES'}
for x in dic:
    for y in dic[x]:
        y.append(dic1)
print dic
```

**output:**

```
{'BOB': [['AUDI', 'BLACK', 'PETROL', {'ALLOY': 17, 'SUNROOF': 'YES', 'TYRE': 'RUBBER'}], ['MINI', 'PINK', 'PETROL', {'ALLOY': 17, 'SUNROOF': 'YES', 'TYRE': 'RUBBER'}], ['VW', 'BLUE', 'DIESEL', {'ALLOY': 17, 'SUNROOF': 'YES', 'TYRE': 'RUBBER'}]], 'DAVE': [['BMW', 'PURPLE', 'PETROL', {'ALLOY': 17, 'SUNROOF': 'YES', 'TYRE': 'RUBBER'}], ['VOLVO', 'GREY', 'PETROL', {'ALLOY': 17, 'SUNROOF': 'YES', 'TYRE': 'RUBBER'}]]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding your additional dict to each list in the values, which are lists themselves. These are mutable, so just reference these inner lists directly:

```
for valuelist in yourdict.values():
    for sublist in valuelist:
        sublist.append(yourotherdict.copy())
```

Note the use of `.copy()` there; we are creating a new copy of the `yourotherdict` structure for appending each time, otherwise they will all be the *same dict* and manipulating one will manipulate all of the references in each list.